# Show that there exists f-stable subspace for certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let K be field. Assume that the characteristic of $K$ is not equal to $2$. Let $f:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator such that $f(f(v))=v$ for any $v \in V$. Show that there exist f-stable subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $V$ such that

i) $V=V_1 \bigoplus V_2$

ii) $f(v_1)=v_1$

iii) $f(v_2)=-v_2$

for all $v_1 \in V_1, v_2 \in V_2$.

Really not sure where to start with this. Hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are defined in the statement, take $V_1=\ker(f-I)$ and $V_2=\ker(f+I)$ then prove that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$.

Comment: I get that if you suppose $v \in V_1 \cap V_2$ then $-f(v)=v=f(v) \implies 2f(v)=0 \implies f(v)=0$ so by linearity $v=0$. How do you show that $V=V_1+V_2$?

Comment: $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1=\frac{1}{2}(v+f(v))$ and $v_2=\frac{1}{2}(v-f(v))$.